# Factorial function does not work with large numbers

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to code a function that calculates the factorial of a given number which I defined as follows:

```
unsigned long long int fact(unsigned long long int n){
    return (n == 0 || n == 1) ? 1 : fact(n - 1) * n;
}
```

and my main function is:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    unsigned long long int z;
    cout << "Please eneter the number: ";
    cin >> z;
    z = fact(z);
    cout << z << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The code works fine until 20 but after that garbage value is returned.

I know I can solve the problem using an array **but I don't understand why the program runs in such a behavior?**

Comment: out of curiosity: what do you mean with "solve the problem using an array"?

Comment: I guess the OP means writing some multiple precision arithmetic code

Comment: @tobi303 https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/factorial-large-number/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

21! is a large number, which exceeds what unsigned long long can hold. You simply get an overflow of the data type.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `unsigned` integer types always "wrap around to zero" whenever they would overflow.

Comment: What could hold 21!? thats what OP would like i'd say!

Comment: Nothing builtin can hold such large numbers (well, floating-point types can, but you lose precision), for arbitrary-precision integer arithmetic, you need to write extra datatypes or use a library for it.

Comment: @L_Church OP is asking to explain the behavior of his code.  And `unsigned long long` is the largest standard fundamental integer type. It's guaranteed to be at least 64 bits, meanining it's guaranteed to be able to store 20! but not 21!. It might be possible for a platform to offer a larger integer type. Check `uintmax_t`, though relying on the extended range of representable values for such an integer type would not be portable.

Comment: Op could use something like ```__uint128_t```  from ```stdint.h``` if op is on a system that has it defined. This will get them a little farther.